Lagged range in if statement
I have successfully used lagged values in the "IF" section of a replace.  How do I specify a range instead of each individual lagged variables.  Iteration is not an option.  I have ~10million observations.
{
g buy2=0
replace buy2 = 5 if buy2[_n-1]==0  & buy2[_n-2]==0
}

As expected in buy2, the 0 was replaced with a 5 every third observation.
My problem is I need this from _n-1 - _n-900 without typing each out or iterating.

If buy2 is 5 after runs of 0 of length 900, then you want
gen buy2 = 0 
replace buy2 = 5 if mod(_n, 901) == 0 

although that seems a fairly unusual thing to want.

Perfect.  Thanks for your help.  back testing a trading system
